# Angular2 routerOnActivate on router 3.0.0-rc.1

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I use Angular2 RC.4 with Router3 rc.1.

How can I implement `routerOnActivate`?

```
import { OnActivate  } from '@angular/router';
```

gives me the error that the module has not the exoprted member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet fully implemented as it is target for release, documentation seems a bit ahead. As stated [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4015#issuecomment-217678683)

> In my opinion this is the most critical piece of functionality missing
>   from Angular 2.0 today. I was able to get by using @brandonroberts
>   OnActivate workaround, but now that it's gone in the release candidate
>   I'm feeling a little high and dry here! I hesitate to use a third
>   party solution like ngrx/router or ui-router so early in the life of
>   this project.

due to ngconf, rc was a bit premature I guess.

Even @brandonroberts workshop at ngconf didn't cover resolving data before loading routes because that mechanism doesn't exist in the new router yet.

Can you use a guard instead? These work for me today pretty fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import anything to use `routerOnActivate()`. Inside your component you can directly use `routerOnActivate(){}` like the way you use `ngOnInit(){}` function.

```js
export class DummyComponent() {
  
  ngOnInit() {
    // Do somehting here
  }
  
  routerOnActivate() {
    // Do something else here
  }
}
```